# How to open OLE2 Compound Document Storage database?

Tags: storage, database, elementary-os

I have file called Thumbs.db that I seem unable to open with anything. SQLite Database Browser can't do it, nor can LibreOffice Base. Opening up the file properties tells me it's an 'OLE2 Compound Document Storage' file.

I'm running elementaryOS (an Ubuntu derivative) on a HP Folio 13.

Comment: `Thumbs.db` is the name used for a [Windows thumbnail cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_thumbnail_cache#Thumbs.db) file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a proprietary Microsoft format.  According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80620/how-to-open-ole2-file-format-document), there's a independent utility called [ripOLE](http://www.pldaniels.com/ripole/) that may open them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ticked it because it should work and so you get the reputaton points, but I just took an easier route and borrowed a Windows computer from a friend to go through the file.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [libgsf](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libgsf/) which probably can list and unpack these files. On Ubuntu, you have to install the package `libgsf-bin` and you get the utility `gsf`. Type `man gsf` for the usage information.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libgsf/-/blob/master/tools/gsf.c

Another kind of OLE2 file is the `.msg` file format. In that case, a better option is the Perl utility [msgconvert](https://superuser.com/a/979603/523252) instead. It's better because it converts the a multipart OLE2 message into a multipart MIME message that Thunderbird can open via GUI.